# What's the correct way to store data in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

My example is like this:

I want to store `Alerts`. For example I have `Alert Type1`, `Alert Type2`, etc..

Each alert type can have different fields, for example:

- `Alert Type1`: { customer, incident_time, file.. }
- `Alert Type2`: { customer, incident_time, user.. }

Option 1:
Keep all the alerts under a single `Index` and each alert with a different type

Option 2:
Keep an `Index` per alert which will keep each index small

What are the pros and cons of each approach?

The searches I will do are mostly on the `customer` field and the `incident_time` fields, but also many queries will be done on a specific `Alert Type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the number of alert / per day you are expecting but I think the best option is the number 3 :D

Option 3: Keep all the alerts under a single `Index` with the same type. And use filters at query time.

Usage of different types under one index is deprecated since version 5, cant be done in version 6 and will be definitively removed in version 7.

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or later may only contain a single mapping type. Indices created in 5.x with multiple mapping types will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Mapping types will be completely removed in Elasticsearch 7.0.0.

See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html) for more information

Don't use multiple types Index unless you want to have a major refactor while upgrading to newer versions of Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yea, actually I just read about it and option number 3 is what I am going to do, thx